# How do I enable VDPAU hardware video acceleration support for non Nvidia cards?

Tags: intel-graphics, ati, video-player, vdpau

I've read about VDPAU and how it enables mplayer to have Hardware acceleration. But i also read that it's only for Nvidia cards

How can i enable it on a non Nvidia card (mine it's a AMD but i would like to enable this in an Intel netbook too)? and will this work for other video players?

Comment: VDPAU afaik is a "Nvidia Only" Tech

Comment: Does AMD have something like it for it's cards then?.

Comment: Ati has XVBA But i'd never heard of it since 2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VDPAU is a programming interface (API) to allow offloading of graphics rendering to the Graphics Chipset rather than handling by the CPU itself.

It is opensource - produced initially by Nvidia themselves and supported on most of their current Graphics Cards.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) has an excellent article on this:

> S3 Graphics added support for VDPAU to the Linux drivers of its Chrome
>   400 video cards since version 14.02.17 of its device driver for Linux,
>   it supports the S3 Chrome 430 GT, S3 Chrome 440 GTX, S3 Chrome 530 GT
>   and the S3 Chrome 540 GTX hardware.
>
> Intel and ATI currently offer no support for VDPAU. Nvidia hopes these
>   GPU designers will support the open source VDPAU library and provide
>   drivers with VDPAU acceleration by mentioning example names of
>   hardware specific drivers for Intel and ATI: libvdpau_intel.so and
>   libvdpau_ati.so.

Intel currently support their own rival API called [VA-API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API).

ATI/Radeon are concentrating their efforts on their Catalyst Drivers - again they have their [own API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Video_Bitstream_Acceleration) called XVBA but is only supported through their Catalyst Drivers.

Phoronix over the last few months have been reporting the development of another API called the [Gallium 3D State Tracker](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?52837-Gallium3D-VDPAU-On-Radeon-Starts-Working) - this is [intended to unify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium3D) the main chipsets - Intel, ATI/Radeon and NVidia.  In simple terms (as far as I understand it) - it tries to overlay an API ontop of VA-API, VDPAU etc.  Thus you program to the Gallium API and it will translate this to the rival APIs for you.

Much of this is *bleeding edge* code - unstable and you will often have to compile code etc to keep up with the latest developments.  The X-Edgers PPA is a good source of latest developments - an [article here](http://brainacle.com/how-to-easily-enable-r600g-gallium3d-in-ubuntu-and-ubuntu-derivatives-for-radeon.html) described installing the opensource radeon driver and forcing the use of Gallium3D.

Back to topic... as you can see, graphics in linux is currently fractured (some call it a mess!) - thus the best solutions at the moment is to use media players that attempt to implement the rival API's such as MPlayer.

---

**UPDATE**

The above was the past ... 2011
At the present 2015, VDPAU is supported by `intel` and `amd` as well as [archWiki page stats](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VDPAU)

You should install the following package for intel

```
sudo apt-get install libvdpau-va-gl1 i965-va-driver
```

but looks there is an [open bug on Ubuntu 14.04 and on 14.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvdpau/+bug/1300215) as well, so the lib is not found ... so for ex. vlc through the following error:

```
Failed to open VDPAU backend i965_drv_video.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There is a workaround in the bug page, I'm not coping it here because even if I apply it the video is not playing in vlc ( looks the library is broken )

Answer (score 5):

for long time I suffered bad *flash player* performance on my intel based notebook. After time passed I decided to put effort on it and created wrapper library that implements  VDPAU interface by means of OpenGL. On systems with VA-API available (like one I have) it also accelerates video decoding. There is one-half or one-third of whole VDPAU functionality implemented, but that's enough to make both *flash player* and *mplayer* work.

You can find code at github: https://github.com/i-rinat/libvdpau-va-gl